# Obtain access to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive of a different user than current

Tags: delphi, registry

I have a service application that needs to access the registry hive of a user to retrieve a license needed for starting an application from the service. How do I go about this?

Comment: _HKEY_CURRENT_USER_ content is created at user logon time (it's not persistent). If you want the persistent value try getting it from _HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_ or _HKEY_USERS\%USER_SID%_.

Comment: Why can't the service account be licensed for the application directly?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a more pure way with raw API calls all the way but if you're a Windows n00b like me, chances are you'd rather have functionality similar to the TRegistry class to access keys and values once you're inside.

Here is a small expansion class to TRegistry I've made to obtain access of HKCU of another user:

```
unit HKCURegistry_;

interface
uses Registry, Windows, SysUtils;

type
  THKCURegistry = class(TRegistry)
    private
      Function Reg_OpenCurrentUser : Integer;
      Function ImpersonateUser(const User, PW : String) : boolean;
    public
      Function OpenUserRegHive( const User, PW : String) : integer;
      Function Revert : boolean;
  end;

implementation

function THKCURegistry.ImpersonateUser(const User, PW: String): boolean;
var
  TokenHandle : THandle;
begin
  Result := LogonUser(pChar(User), pChar(''), pChar(PW), LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, TokenHandle);
  if Result then
    Result := ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(TokenHandle);
end;

function THKCURegistry.Reg_OpenCurrentUser: Integer;
var
  key : HKEY;
begin
  Result := RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_READ, &key);
  self.SetCurrentKey(key);
end;

function THKCURegistry.OpenUserRegHive(const User, PW: String): integer;    
begin
  if ImpersonateUser( User, PW ) then begin
    Result := Reg_OpenCurrentUser;
  end else raise Exception.Create('Unable to log on user ' + User + ' with password ' + PW);
end;

function THKCURegistry.Revert: boolean;
begin
  Result := RevertToSelf;
end;

end.
```

The class inherits TRegistry and overloads none of the baseclass functionality. OpenUserRegHive is the poster child of the class, it impersonates a different user and gives access to his/her HKCU registry hive. The Revert call resets the impersonation, the rest is TRegistry hauling weight.

Comment: Where are you going to get the password from?

Answer (score 0):

You can read from HKEY_USERS\SID

```
function GetCurrentUserSID:String;
var
  objSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  objWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  objWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  oEnum           : IEnumvariant;
  oWmiObject      : OLEVariant;
  iValue          : LongWord;
  SDummy          : AnsiString;
Begin
  objSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  objWMIService   := objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost','root\cimv2', '','');
  objWbemObjectSet:= objWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Account','WQL',0);
  oEnum           := IUnknown(objWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  {'Name','Domain','SID', Status}
  while oEnum.Next(1, oWmiObject, iValue) = 0 do
    begin
      SDummy:=VarStrNull(oWmiObject.Properties_.Item('SID').Value);
      //SDummy:= SDummy + VarStrNull(oWmiObject.Properties_.Item('Domain').Value);
      //SDummy:= SDummy +  VarStrNull(oWmiObject.Properties_.Item('Status').Value);
      oWmiObject:=Unassigned;
    end;
  Result:= SDummy;
End;
```

Comment: Please explain your code a little bit so we can understand your logic.